# Android - Is there a way to share a Wi-Fi connection with a connected peripheral device over BLE seamlessly?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi

I know that there are ways to share internet via:

1. Creating a hot spot on the mobile phone
2. Bluetooth tethering?
3. NFC tags

However all these processes require some manual effort on the user side.

I am wondering if there is a way to seamlessly do this for the user the moment we pair with their peripheral device over BLE. Is there a way I can programmatically share the Wi-Fi connection the moment we are successfully connected?

Use Case:

1. I have a new speaker that can connect over BLE
2. I successfully pair my phone with the speaker over BLE
3. **My speaker after pairing also automatically joins the same wifi network as my phone after**